# fsevents.watch error running Gatsby hello-world example

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to do the "Set up your development environment" tutorial on macOS Mojave. Everything is fine until I try to run `gatsby develop`. When do, I get the errors: "UNHANDLED REJECTION fsevents.watch is not a function" and "TypeError: fsevents.watch is not a function". Does anyone know what to do about that??

Answer (score 0):

I apparently had old node remnants that I had to get rid of for my homebrew node installation to work properly. I did

```
brew uninstall node
sudo rm -rf ~/.node
brew install node
```

and then I could run `gatsby develop` successfully.